# Automatic IE compatibility mode change

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I am currently having one requirement in which i need to have one BAT file which opens IE with a concrete URL. This is quite easy but my main problem is that the website of that URL is only running under compatibility mode IE8 and whenever I execute IE it is raised as IE9 Compat Mode

[image]

As this BAT file will be published on Citrix I need that any user that executes it will be automatically getting this setting instead of having to mannually change it...

Is there any way I can set it on the BAT file? Maybe using execution parameters for IE or maybe some Registry change?

The version installed on that machine is IE8...

Thanks a lot in advance for your reply!

Best rregards

Biel

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by modifying the registry. Create and execute the following .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\BrowserEmulation\PolicyList]
"stackoverflow.com"="stackoverflow.com"
```

Just replace the "stackoverflow.com" with your URL.

Comment: Done so but the browser still shows with compatibility for IE9... Shouldnt I specify somewhere which option do I need for it?

Comment: Just as extra information i am able to make it work by changing it on the development tools raised by pressing F12... With the compatibility view settings that are modified using this script I have not been able to show correctly the website... :(

Are those different things? How can I update in regsitry the one in the development tool bar (screenshot shared in first message)

Comment: Is anyone aware of some other method? I wonder whether that specific option on the Development tools of IE can be changed by registry or other command using CMD...